# Entering the UK while undergoing visa application

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I spent 6 months in the UK last year (February to August 2016) under a Tier 2 Skills Transfer visa from the US on a US passport.

I will be starting the Tier 2 General visa process with my US employer to move to our UK office in the next month or so. Currently they are undergoing the labor market test.

I have a close friend's wedding in the UK the first weekend of September and I am wondering if I will be able to enter the country while undergoing a separate visa application. I would enter the country after the 12 month cool down period from my visa last year and would have a return ticket to show them I am entering as a tourist (for now).

Will I likely be allowed in? Will entering the UK complicate my current visa application at all? If everything goes smoothly, I should have visa stamp by the end of September or early October.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Kind regards,
JV

Comment: Since this concerns a short trip to the UK as a visitor, you might try asking at [Travel.SE].

Comment: Do you have 2 passports? As you will be sending one in with the T2 application.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.